After Updating from Laravel 10 to 11 I am getting an artisan error
I upgraded to 11 but now I get the following error when I try to run any artisan command:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\LaravelVOPlanning\admin/bootstrap/app.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes') in C:\Laravel\VOPlanning\admin\artisan:12

the line in question in artisan is
// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the command...
$status = (require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleCommand(new ArgvInput);

There

does the good old composer dump-autoload help? oh and make sure the file is actually there.

when you change l10 to l11 you use the  withCommands ref on bootstrap/app.php. That don't have handleCommand
